# Installation from a Live USB changes the network device name (eth0, eth1, ...)

Tags: live-usb

I have created a live usb from terminal using the following command,

`usb-creator-gtk`

now the problem is when i install the first system using this live usb, it assigns the network device of the 1st machine as eth0. However when i install the second machine using this same live usb it assigns the network device of the 2nd machine as eth1 and third as eth2 and so on. Why this happens? How to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you happen to have a Live USB with persistence?

Comment: What you mean by persistence?

Comment: Persistence is that the data is saved when the session is closed which means that the settings and documents from a session will be used the next time the Live USB boots.

Comment: How to check whether my live usb is with persistene or not?

Comment: Boot into it, create a file in the home directory / change a configuration file in `/etc`, reboot the Live USB and check if the modifications are still there. You can also check for an additional file on the Live USB, but I forgot the name.

Comment: Yes the modifications are there. How come this happens? How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the startup disk, select *Discard on shutdown, unless you save them elsewhere*. To disable this option by default, run `usb-creator-gtk -n`. Below is a screenshot of the first situation.

[image: Make Startup Disk]